# Socket unable to receive bytes

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a packet sniffer using sockets for learning purposes. On the tutorials I see, it seems to be pretty straightforward. First create a socket (in my case TCP), then receive incoming packets.

This is my current code in Python, however it does not work. My program stops running at `recvfrom` and I do not know why.

```
import socket, sys
from struct import *
# import os

def main():    
    # default port for socket 
    port = 80
    
    # 1) create an INET, raw socket
    try: 
        # socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
        print "Socket successfully created"
    except socket.error , msg:
        print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()

    while True:       
        packet = socket1.recvfrom(1000) # HALTS HERE
        print("after recvfrom")
```

Comment: You should cut and paste (not screenshot) the error you're getting.  You should also use Python 3 code in a Python 3 interpreter.  Do not use Python 2 code in either 2.x or 3.x interpreters anymore.  Those print statements scream "this is Python 2" code.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket is not connected to anything (as a client), nor is it bound to port (as a server or a connectionless UDP socket).
What did you expect to read from the socket ?